# How to not allow lazy loading from outside the transnational method?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, lazy-evaluation

I'm using JPA with Hibernate and Spring. I have an entity (Say Employee) with an attribute (Say of type Position) and this attribute is **lazy-loaded**.

I believe that when you try to access the position attribute, it will be lazy loaded from the DB and this is done inside the transnational method.

Let's say I didn't access the attribute in that transnational method. So if I tried to access it later, I would get "**org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException**: could not initialize proxy - no Session" which is normal because the session was closed by that transnational method.

At this point, I need it null (or not initialized) wherever I access it later in different method but this is not the case! The question is how can we make it null after committing and closing the session because it is not accessed while the session is open?

Below is a simple code to illustrate the issue.

```
// In some Service class
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Employee getEmployeeById(Integer id) throws Exception {

    Employee emp = employeeDAO.getEmployeeById(id);
    // I didn't access the position attribute here because I don't need it for now
    return emp;
}
```

Later I call the above method (Say from some controller):

```
Employee emp = employeeService.getEmployeeById(904);
System.out.println(emp.getPosition()); // Here, the LazyInitializationException
//would occur, but I need this to be null or at least to prevent the lazy loading, 
//thus, avoiding the exception. How?
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be the answer that you're looking for

[Hibernate - Avoiding LazyInitializationException - Detach Object From Proxy and Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505423/hibernate-avoiding-lazyinitializationexception-detach-object-from-proxy-and)

Basically

- Use Hibernate to check if that field is initialised with `Hibernate. isInitialized(fieldName)`in the getter and return null if not initialised.
- Inside `employeeDAO.getEmployeeById`method, create a new `Employee` object and set the parameters from the one that return from query, which is more work but prevent you to couple your domain to Hibernate.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I guess the Hibernate should be smarter than that and provide a way to "reset" the detached object - after completing the transaction -.